# detect screen resolution then compare

Tags: javascript, screen-resolution

I've problem with my css sheet of one page ,So been thinking to detect screen resolution if equal or less than 800 pixel width it will makes my css code is

```
<style>
body {width:1004px;}
</style>
```

but if it was greater than 800 pixel width, it will makes my css code is

```
<style>
body {width:100%;}
</style>
```

so anyone knows js code that code do it !!
i only care about width detection no need to detect the hights as well.
i've made search for alot of js code doing this but wasn't able to use to do this exact function of passing either of those css code into the page.

Comment: Why not use `CSS media query` for this problem ? [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Comment: This effect is typically called utilizing [responsive design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design), and the modern solution for this does not rely on JavaScript at all. Rather, use **CSS media queries**.

Comment: @Vucko Thanks never knew about CSS media query before ! will read about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

```
body {
  width:100%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    width:1004px;
  }
}
```